# Way calculation of a function in Haskell using composition

Tags: haskell

I have this function in haskell:

```
thrit::(a->a)->a->a
thrit f= f.f.f
```

and I want to know how the computer calculate the expressions to get the answer:

`((thrit.thrit)(+1))0`     its 9

`((thrit thrit)(+1))0`     its 27

Comment: Have you tried to manually reason how `thrit` and `(.)` would be expanded? For example `thrit (+1) = (+1).(+1).(+1)`, and so on.

Comment: Yes 3 I understand, but I'm not sure in what way we reach to 9 and 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand the expressions

`((thrit . thrit) (+1)) 0` = `(thrit (thrit (+1)) 0` = `(thrit ((+1) . (+1) . (+1))) 0`
= `((+1) . (+1) . (+1) . (+1) . (+1) . (+1) . (+1) . (+1) . (+1)) 0`

which is 9

`((thrit thrit) (+1)) 0` = `((thrit . thrit . thrit) (+1)) 0` = `(thrit (thrit (thrit (+1))) 0`

You may have noticed `(thrit (thrit (thrit (+1))) 0` is just three times `(thrit (thrit (+1)) 0`

hence 27

Answer (score 0):

prM did a good job answering this question, but I'd like to take it a step further.

Let's look at the definition of `(.)`:

```
infixr9 . -- right associative
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Now let's expand `thrit` according to this definition, noting that `(.)` is right associative:

```
thrit::(a -> a) -> a -> a
thrit f = f . f . f

thrit f = f . (f . f)                -- group terms
thrit f = f . (\x -> f (f x))        -- expansion
thrit f = \y -> f (\x -> f (f x)) y  -- more expansion
thrit f = \y -> f (f (f y))          -- reduction
thrit   = \f -> \y -> f (f (f y))    -- lambda abstraction
```

To evaluate `thrit (+1)`, we just substitute `f` for `(+1)` at all occurrences:

```
thrit (+1) = \y -> (+1) ((+1) ((+1) y))
           = \y -> (((y+1)+1)+1)
```

Noting that `thrit . thrit` is just an alias for `(f . f . f) . (f . f . f)`, we can use the definitions above and expand them out:

```
thrit . thrit = (\f -> \y -> f (f (f y))) . (\g -> \z -> g (g (g z)))
              = \h -> (\f -> \y -> f (f (f y))) ((\g -> \z -> g (g (g z))) h)
              = \h -> (\f -> \y -> f (f (f y))) (\z -> h (h (h z)))
              = \h -> (\y -> (\z -> h (h (h z))) ((\z -> h (h (h z))) ((\z -> h (h (h z))) y)))
              = \h -> (\y -> (\z -> h (h (h z))) ((\z -> h (h (h z))) (h (h (h y))))
              = \h -> (\y -> (\z -> h (h (h z))) (h (h (h (h (h (h y)))))))
              = \h -> (\y -> (h (h (h (h (h (h (h (h (h y))))))))))
```

Applied to `(+1)`, this gives the following expression:

```
(thrit . thrit) (+1) = \y -> ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) ((+1) y)))))))))
```

Which finally desugars to:

```
(thrit . thrit) (+1) = \y -> ((((((((y+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1
```

I'm not going to go through the expansion of `(thrit . thrit . thrit)`, and you can probably see why. :)